# 2nd half of proof of $\dim V^G=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g) $

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

**Lemma.** Let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation, character $\chi$. Then

$$\dim V^G=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g) $$

**Proof.** RHS: $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}tr \rho(g)=\frac{1}{|G|}tr \sum_{g \in G} \rho(g)$$.

Let $\displaystyle M:=\sum_{g \in G} \rho(g)$. $M$ is a linear map: $V \rightarrow V$ and image lands in $V^G$ since $\rho(h)\sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)v= \sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)$.

I do not understand how what they are trying to do in the bit "since $\rho(h)\sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)v= \sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)$.". I can see that somehow it is related in to G-invariance. In particular I am struggling to see what the $\rho(h)$ is related to and why and how it acts on $\sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement
$$\rho(h)\sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)v = \sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)v$$
should have the $v$ that I've included in the right hand side.  Then it is exactly the statement that the image of $M$ lands in $V^G$.  This is because if $v$ is any vector and $M = \sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)$ then $\sum_{g \in G}\rho(g)v = Mv$ is what a vector in the image of $M$ looks like.  Now the above statement says $\rho(h)Mv = Mv$.  In other words, $\rho(h)$ fixes the vector $Mv$ for all $h$ so $Mv \in V^G$.

Comment: I cant quite see the point of the $\rho(h)$ and where it goes

Comment: To show something is in $V^G$ you have you show that for any $h \in G$ it doesn't change when you act on it by $\rho(h)$.

Comment: For where it goes see mich95's answer.

Comment: How do we know though that the action will be by left multiplication?

Comment: The definition of a representation $\rho\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is that $\rho$ is a homomorphism and $g$ acts on $V$ via the transformation $\rho(g)$.  Acting by a transformation is written as left multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

The set $ \lbrace hg: g \in G \rbrace $ =$G$.  (You're making h act by left multipliation on $G$ which defines a bijection on G). (In other words, as g ranges over G exactly once, then so will $hg$ hence the $\sum\limits_{g \in G} \rho(hg)=\sum\limits_{hg \in G} \rho(hg) =\sum\limits_{g \in G} \rho(g)$